# Django: If I already deployed my app and want to make a change, how I manage the static files?

Tags: django, deployment

I already deployed my Django app, but now I'd like to make some changes to it, and I'll edit some static files too. Once I redeploy the app, should I run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` or should I do something else?

Comment: for applying any changes in static files to production, collectstatic will be enough

Comment: @Sumithran okay so it won't duplicate the files right?

Comment: no, it won't duplicate files.